# safari not filling vertical with grid-auto-flow: column

Tags: css, safari, css-grid

Using `grid-auto-flow: column` in safar1 v.13 vertical space is not being filled.

[image: safari grid]

Works fine in chrome/ff

[image: chrome grid]

Any advice?

Comment: Please post all relevant code in a snippet, so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Michael_B not so easy; a react test page https://github.com/HenrikBechmann/Tribalopolis/blob/master/src/ui/system/test.controller.tsx Here's the component root code https://github.com/HenrikBechmann/Tribalopolis/blob/master/src/ui/common/iscrollbygrid.tsx

Comment: @Michael_B here's the grid root code https://github.com/HenrikBechmann/Tribalopolis/blob/master/src/ui/common/iscrollbygrid/cradle.tsx all under early development as you can see

Comment: Have you tried adding a height to the grid container? Add `height: 100%` or `height: 100vh`.

Comment: Yes, thanks, you can see 100% on the chrome screenshot (same code). Looks like I'm just going to have to live with it - Safari apparently takes the height from the minmax, without stretching the track contents to fill. Presumably this will resolve over time. I even tried writing-mode options -- just causes more problems

Comment: btw the test page (for now) is at tribalopolis.com/test

Comment: Try adding `height: 100%` to the child of `<div style="position: relative; height: 500px;">`. It doesn't have any height specified. It may be the missing link.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
grid-template-rows: max-content
```

to parent.